# Jenkins not starting Kubernetes pod agent

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on `2.414.2`, using the Kubernetes Jenkins plugin version `4029.v5712230ccb_f8`, and the Kubernetes client API Jenkins plugin version `6.8.1-224.vd388fca_4db_3b_`. I've recently upgraded to these versions of these plugins - previously the Kubernetes Jenkins plugin was on version `1.30.1` and the client API was on `5.4.1`.

Since upgrading the Kubernetes plugins to the new versions, Jenkins can no longer connect to my Kubernetes cluster, and runs into the following errors:

```
Error testing connection https://whatever.this.is.my.kuberetes.cluster: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 503
```

When trying to run a Jenkins pipeline with the following Jenkinsfile (which previously worked with the older Kubernetes plugin versions), I get the following error:

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      inheritFrom 'nodejs-16'
      yamlMergeStrategy merge()
      defaultContainer 'nodejs'
    }
...
```

Error that I'm seeing:

```
ERROR: Failed to launch my-pod-75-sk4x3-0fcx3-bb1r1
java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 503
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.kt:483)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.kt:262)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 503
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.waitForResult(OperationSupport.java:504)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:524)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:340)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:703)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:92)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:42)
Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:129)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:122)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.CreateOnlyResourceOperation.create(CreateOnlyResourceOperation.java:44)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:133)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:297)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I also see this error if I try testing the connection to Kubernetes through the Kubernetes Cloud view in the Jenkins dashboard.

Another thing to note is that my Kubernetes cluster does not appear to be getting messages from Jenkins anymore, I see no attempts of Jenkins trying to start a pod on the Kubernetes side of things.

Has anyone seen an issue like this before, or has any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: have you checked the the certificate, the namespace,  Jenkins URL
,and Jenkins tunnel ?